# Is listening to Music on the fast of Asarah BeTevet permitted?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, music

Can you listen to music on the fast of the tenth of tevet?

Comment: Related (broader): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51244/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio It is broader, but it also addressed this specific question exactly, with a source (well, at least a name of someone who prohibited it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What activities (other than eating and drinking) are forbidden on minor fasts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51244/what-activities-other-than-eating-and-drinking-are-forbidden-on-minor-fasts)

Comment: In shiur this year the Rav said that the minor fasts should be treated *at least* like the nine days. In fact, originally they considered making it like Tish'a B'Av before deciding to make it only during the day and not forbid leather shoes. However, it is a day of mourning to an extent.

Answer (score 8):

[Nitei Gavriel - Chanuka - 60:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=363) says that one should not listen to music on a fast day.

(sources: Rokeiach, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 121:1)

Comment: Who is Rabbi Gavriel Zinner?

Comment: @AniYodeya http://www.vosizneias.com/81017/2011/04/17/brooklyn-ny-hamodia-interviews-noted-halacha-expert-rav-gavriel-zinner-on-pesach/

Comment: The Rokeiach is quite a big work. Does he give anything more precise?

Comment: @DoubleAA: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=76

Comment: The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch doesn't say this. He says (my translation): "The essence is not the fasting... the fast is only a preparation for teshuva. Therefore, when fasting, people who go on trips/strolls and while away their time with useless activities have grasped the secondary aspect of the fast and abandoned its primary aspect." Clearly, he does not indicate a formal prohibition against listen to music, as implied by the *Nit'ei Gavriel*.

Comment: Please clarify source for Rokeah, and more importantly that Kitsur doesn't say what the NG claims. While it is difficult to fault you for believing the NG, but it is similarly hard to accept (not in the technical sense) an answer that continues to state information that has shown to probably be false.

Comment: Nitei Gavriel simply feels it is inappropriate.  Here is his reference to Hilchos Bein Hametzarim, where he states this clearly and brings the source for the Rokeach http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=76

Comment: It can thus be supported by the Kitzur he brought

Comment: @Fred Nitei Gavriel never says it is a formal prohibition, see my refernce above

Comment: @רבותמחשבות In the book on Chanuka he says אין רשאין and in Bein Hametsarim he says אין נכון (quoting the Rokeach who says אין לזמר ולשורר). He seems to be representing the Rokeach's view accurately when he implies it's forbidden, and is probably bringing the Kitsur Shulchan Aruch as an "אסמכתא בעלמא"

Comment: @ba I had seen that.  I originally intended to argue that Ein Rashain is still not technically Assur, just a very strong "not supposed to" (because he doesn't say Assur), but what you're saying makes sense too.

Answer (score 5):

In the Shulchan Aruch it does not say that music is prohibited on the 10th of Tevet, however the Mishnah Berurah (550:6) writes that a person who can (and is a ba’al nefesh) should preferably accept the stringencies of Tisha Be’Av even for the other fasts. ([source](http://dinonline.org/2012/01/05/music-on-tenth-of-teves/))

That one should not listen to live music on Tisha B'Av is [codified by many later authorities](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Three_Weeks#cite_note-72) and it is assumed to be absent from the SA because there’s a general prohibition of Listening to Music (ibid)

Comment: Are you implying that there is a formal restriction on music on 9 Av? Source?

Comment: This would be a more meaningful answer if you quoted the tremendous chiddush of the article that this means the 9 days, as well as providing a source that there is a formal restriction of listening to music then.

Comment: Excellent edit, +1!  That itself should be the answer for all fast days.